# How is this SHA-1 hash generated?

Tags: cryptography, sha

If you get a disposable email from say [guerrillamail.com](http://guerrillamail.com), and then fill out the forgot my password page at [dahorta.org/app/index.php/cliente/resgatar_senha](http://dahorta.org/app/index.php/cliente/resgatar_senha), it emails you a link to reset your password. The url has a 40 character number which I think is a SHA-1 hash.

I noticed that when you fill out the same email twice you get two different hashes. With multiple hashes, will it be possible to guess the algorithm?

Comment: Luiz - if it is SHA-1, the algorithm is known, but it is obviously being salted. But there is nothing there which confirms that is a SHA-1 hash, so there is no way to tell what the algorithm is other than ask the folks at guerrillamail. So this is not a security question as per the site scope.

Comment: @RoryAlsop The hash is always 40 characters. Doesnt that narrow the set of possible algorithms?